# XSL transform with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my source XML
[Source XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTAUd.jpg)

I'm trying to extract value of  **"StatusCode"**

This is my XSL transform:

[XSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXLve.jpg)

Without Namespace its working fine.

I have declared all of the namespaces.
Do I need to declare any additional ones?

Comment: Please post the code here as text here instead of posting an image. Please read the help on the MarkDown syntax to properly format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateResponse` element and all of its descendants are in the namespace `http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI`.

You need to declare this namespace in your XSLT and bind it to a prefix. You can then use that prefix in your XPath.

For example...

Bind `http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI` to prefix `papi`:

```
xmlns:papi="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
```

Use the prefix:

```
<xsl:value-of 
    select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/papi:CreateResponse/papi:Results/papi:StatusCode"/>
```

Also, like Martin Zabel mentioned in the comments, please add your XML and XSLT to the question itself instead of linking images. This will help future visitors by ensuring the complete context of the question is always available.